# How to use vue to dynamically add new messages and when new messages are generated, the window can be scrolled to the latest message position?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently I use `vue` to write a message that can be entered and dynamically added to the chat blue area, but when the message continues to increase, I must use the mouse to see the latest message. How can I achieve it like a chat room? Can the screen scroll to the latest message position when a new message is generated?

thank you all

[example](https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/LYyaGXM)

Comment: `I can use innerHTML` - I've done a lot of vue code - and have never once touched innerHTML - you do realise your example fails to even instantiate vue - you seem to be loading multiple vue libraries

Comment: Hello~ Does it mean that innerHTML should not be used?

Comment: Your Codepen does not work, because you've forgot to add `Vue` to the page. For example, by adding [script tag](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html).

Comment: @fromaline no, he's added it ... twice ... once from cdnjs, and then again from unpkg

Comment: @WEIA - no, but certainly not the way you are, completely wiping out your main vue element - or, attempting to, except you've loaded vue wrong

Comment: @Bravo, yeah, he've just updated it.

Comment: @fromaline - nope, been like that for 6 minutes

Comment: I know the problem! I wrote a new one~ and asked another question! thank you all